# How to create formulas in share point - quality assessment

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I'm new to this forum and just want some help on the basics.

I want to create a Quality Assessment form and want to know how to create formulas that are not Yes or No answer.

For example:

> Score of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & NA
>
> 5 being excellent.

Additionally, how do I add the total of this section to the overall Quality Assessment marking that is a Yes or No or NA score.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement, so that you can get more attention. You can elaborate your question with some example or brief description on What? How? Where?. You can refer these guidelines http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Those are Likert questions and are only supported in Survey lists.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you want to achieve with your score formula, but you can check this list for functions supported in the calculated field column: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

Start with learning Excel functions and prototype your requirements in Excel.

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Shows you the (Excel) functions that do work in SharePoint.

With basic IF, OR, AND, ISBLANK functions you can built the Formulas you are after.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you want a word response to show based on the score from column2 and that it needs to have a large range based on the option chosen. This formula should work (may need some tweaking based on column type of column2).

=IF( H3=1, "Bad", IF( H3=2, "Ok", IF( H3=3, "Awesome", "" ) ) )

Here you go. Plug it into excel and modify it till it works as you want it to. Once it works as you want put it into sharepoint and change the column names.

Answer taken and modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14673787/5051773)

**Edit for second part**
To get overall score have another calculated column that adds all the previous score columns together and then make another calculated column and reuse the above formula with the new column.

Comment: This answer can be simplified to **=CHOOSE(H3,"Bad","Ok","Awesome")**